# Exclude static httpcomponent module without excuding resteasy from JBoss EAP 7.1

Tags: jboss, wildfly, jboss7.x

I need to exclude default httpcomponent module from my application, but I also use restasy and don't want to exclude or broke it. For httpcomponent I want to use versions from dependencies in my project. Is it possible with `JBoss EAP 7.1`?

Version of modules in jboss :

> jackson-databind-2.8.9.redhat-1
>
> jackson-core-2.8.9.redhat-1
>
> jackson-annotations-2.8.9.redhat-1

I've tried to add to `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` this config but it didn't help:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.httpcomponents" />     
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson-provider" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider" />
             <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jettison-provider"/>
        </exclusions>
        <dependencies>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Comment: It should be possible and it should work. But if you have any specific issues, please post your configuration and versions of jars in your deployment as well as exception.

Answer (score 0):

It should work, I can provide you a tested example (I've excluded the jettinson provider for my web app):

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.0">
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jettison-provider"/>
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

I see only modules in your question, do you have the correct deployment -> exclusions structure?

If you need a list of JBoss EAP 7 modules, go [here](https://access.redhat.com/articles/2158031).

Comment: sorry missed exclusions tags

Comment: This doesn't helped me, with "objectMapper.getClass().getPackage().getImplementationVersion()"  I still have in result  "2.8.9.redhat-1"

Comment: Matteo Baldi, Do you only exclude "resteasy-jettison-provider" and it is enough? Does Restesy works fine after that?

Comment: No wait, I've posted you an example. My problem was only with the jettison provider so I've excluded it. If you need to exclude something else, go to the link provided (I'm gonna put it in the answer)

Comment: I got it, exclusion is works in general, but for httpcomponents it doesn't work if you don't wanna exclude resteasy.